# Using docker buildx github action cache without official actions

Tags: docker, caching, github-actions, docker-buildkit, github-actions-artifacts

**TL;DR:**

How can I find manually `ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN` and  `ACTIONS_CACHE_URL` in GitHub actions?

**Context**

I am trying to cache docker layers during a buildkit build in GitHub actions.

In theory, it's easy with the `docker/setup-buildx-action`, `docker/build-push-action` and `crazy-max/ghaction-github-runtime` actions. The thing is, I cannot use them (organization policy).

The relevant part of my workflow is now:

```bash
$repo_url= "<ECR repo in aws>"
docker buildx create --use --driver=docker-container
docker buildx build --tag "${repo_url}:latest"  --file docker/Dockerfile . --cache-to "type=gha,mode=max" --cache-from type=gha
```

The caching requires 2 variables/configuration: `ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN` and
`ACTIONS_CACHE_URL`. They would be set up by the `ghaction-github-runtime`, which I thus cannot use. Looking at the code, it seems to export 2 variables from the environment, but I cannot find them.

How can I manually, without the help of other actions, find them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a bit disgusting, but this is the solution I came up with:

First, add permissions to the workflow

```yaml
permissions:
  id-token: write # Important for at least docker gha cache
  contents: read
```

This will give you the environment variables `ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL` and `ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN`.

The Docker gha cache wants 2 variables:

- `ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN`, which is actually `ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN`
- `ACTIONS_CACHE_URL`, which can be inferred from `ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL`. The GitHub variable looks like `https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/<a long id>/<a lot of things>` and `ACTIONS_CACHE_URL`, the docker variable, should be `https://artifactcache.actions.githubusercontent.com/<the long id from above>/`

So my final solution is:

```bash
export ACTIONS_CACHE_URL=$(echo "$ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL" | grep -Po 'https://[^/]+/[^/]+/' | sed 's/pipelines/artifactcache/')
export ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN=$ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN

docker buildx build --load --file docker/Dockerfile . --cache-to "type=gha,mode=max" --cache-from type=gha
```

Now I can use the cache without external actions.

Comment: Thanks; I came across this and the documentation is very poor

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what "official" actions you can actually use, you probably can do more or less same thing as doing with [`actions/github-script`](https://github.com/actions/github-script). Step will look like:

```
    - name: Expose actions cache variables
      uses: actions/github-script@v6
      with:
        script: |
          core.exportVariable('ACTIONS_CACHE_URL', process.env['ACTIONS_CACHE_URL'])
          core.exportVariable('ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN', process.env['ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN'])
```